# a comments thread is closed in meta

Tags: discussion

in [i cannot agree that this question is opinion based](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1246) comments thread is blocked. i cannot do anyting there. answering by writing an answer is not good enough. i think blocking speach is not normal. this should be denied. generally, i think only in cases like flood attack person should be banned, in other cases it is still talkable.

instead of closing the thread, he could request to delete the comment, or delete it by himself.

there is a new topic, "but it would require more research than just finding a single photo". i could say that i made a little research about that, in google, but did not find. (there is a fresh topic about research requirement: [Please make clearer the requirement to include research when asking a question](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1248) ).

Comment: You're lucky all I did was lock comments after you engaged in personal attacks. Free speech has limits here.

Answer (score 3):

Comments have been unlocked on that thread, but please use comments only for what they're intended for or they'll be deleted and locked again.

And note that the thread itself was never locked, only comments on the question. You and everyone else have been free all along to respond with an answer, which was made clear in the lock notice.